# Java editing CSV files specific cells. Reading and updating

Tags: java, csv, edit

Does anyone know how to read and update specific cells in csv files. Is there a plugin or something?

For exmaple code like

```
csv.updateCell(row,col,;val');
```

or

```
csv.readCell(row,col);
```

It needs to be a jar library that can be used on all Operating systems (windows, osx, linux etc)

Does anyone know what library should be used and how this would be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You may try a JDBC driver for MS Excel, as Excel is capable of dealing with CSV files.

Here are some:

[sqlsheet](http://code.google.com/p/sqlsheet/), [Excel JDBC driver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlsql/)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use [opencsv](https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/) library.

This library allows you to read an update csv files easily. Try to use this library if you will have some problems, update your question with some code fragment.

**Update 1**

```
public class OpenCsv {

private static final char SEPARATOR = ';';
//private static final char CHAR_SEPARATOR = '';

public void updateCsvFile(String source, String destination) throws Exception{

    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(source),SEPARATOR);
    List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
    csvBody.get(1)[2]="NewValue";

    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(destination),SEPARATOR,' ');
    writer.writeAll(csvBody);
    writer.flush();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //input file lookslike at the following
    //1;2;3
    //4;5;6
    //7;8;9

    String source = "input.csv";
    String destiantion="output.csv";
    OpenCsv opencsv = new OpenCsv();
    try {
        opencsv.updateCsvFile(source, destiantion);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: I looked at it, I don't think it has anything for editing and reading specific cells thoughoes it?

Comment: You can easily read the file where each row is a String[], update the cell/cells and rewite the updated content in another file. All this with a few row of code.

Comment: do you have any examples? It's my first time working with csv files so im a bit confused. I also can't find any documentation for opencsv..

Comment: OpenCSV docs are located here: https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/  A good short tutorial is here: https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv